# How to apply Hierarchize and Order by with MDX Query

Tags: mdx, olap, xmla

I need to order Dimension with respect to descending order. without using HIERARCHIZE key word everything works fine. here i need HIERARCHIZE in order to order hierarchy level data.

```
Select NON EMPTY({[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}) dimension properties MEMBER_TYPE,CHILDREN_CARDINALITY, PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS ,NON EMPTY(HIERARCHIZE({{ORDER(drilldownlevel([Customer].[Customer Geography]),[Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION,desc)}})) dimension properties MEMBER_TYPE,CHILDREN_CARDINALITY, PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the question is - you have a solution : delete hierarchize?

Comment: please reformat the code - I did this before: its now impossible to read again!

Comment: Hi please find the attached screen shot.i hope now its ill be clear

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunely I do not have AdvWrks cube to test the following:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY
     [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY
      ORDER(
         {
           HIERARCHIZE([Customer].[Customer Geography].[COUNTRY].MEMBERS)
          ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[COUNTRY].&[GERMANY].CHILDREN
         }
        ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION
        ,BDESC
      )
    )  ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Looks like I had a tested solution to a similar problem here:
[Issue with Order function and Crossoins in MDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611153/issue-with-order-function-and-crossoins-in-mdx)

Looks like an application of the above to your context is something like this:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      Order
      (
        {
            [Customer].[Customer Geography].[COUNTRY].MEMBERS
         ,  [Customer].[Customer Geography].[COUNTRY].&[GERMANY].CHILDREN
        }
       ,(
          [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
         ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[COUNTRY]
        )
       ,BDESC
      )
    } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12310997)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Formulating an exact answer, in this language, is not always possible. Currently the questioner has self-answered but the reality is that the questioner has not even answered the question they originally asked! ...please see my comment below - the set `[Customer].[Customer Geography].[COUNTRY].MEMBERS` is in their question but not in their answer. Maybe @GregGalloway might like to comment - Greg: do you agree that with the mdx questions it is not always easy to give the questioner precisely what they require but that something like my answer can often be sufficient?

Comment: @JonathanArgentiero also please note that in the original question the script is structured with ORDER nested inside HIERARCHIZE - in my answer I correctly swapped the nesting so that HIERARCHIZE is inside ORDER ..... then look at the users self-answer: swapping this order was, in my mind the important point and I actually felt slightly hard-done by as the user did not even up my answer. But all-in-all no big deal.

Comment: (but even after saying the above I will review my answer as this is the AdvWrks cube and I will be able to create an exact answer - when I am back on a machine that has access to the cube)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issues with below query

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
NON EMPTY
    Order(
        Hierarchize(
           [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany].Children
        )
      ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION
      ,DESC
    )
ON 1
FROM [Adventure works];
```

Comment: this is not the same script that you asked for in the original question - please can you amend it so that it includes the countries such as Canada and France? (I've amended it to get rid of all the redundant braces)